# Extracting quotations from a movie / tv transcript in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

I have a transcript of a 3 hour documentary that is filled with quotes I'd like to share. The transcript is huge so going through it manually would take forever.

So basically, I just want to remove all the text from the transcript except for text found between quote marks: remove "keep" remove.

I'm pretty sure you can do this in Notepad++, I just don't know how. Can someone help please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution to this problem lies in using [RegEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), a tool which matches parts of text given a set of rules. Your rules are fairly simple - catch everything between two quotes. I'm not the greatest at Regex, but I came up with a solution that seems to match what you are looking for.

I recommend using the [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/download) editor to do this - firstly, I couldn't get it to work with ease in N++, and secondly, Sublime is really awesome!

Here's how to extract your quotes.

1. Open the file you want to extract from in Sublime.
2. Hit `ctrl+f` to open the find tool at the bottom of the screen.
3. Hit the button on the far left of the find tool with the `.*` symbols. This enables RegEx matching.
4. In the find bar, type:
   `"[^"]+"`
5. On the far right of the find tool, click `Find All`
6. Hit `ctrl+c` to copy all selections.
7. Open a new file and hit `ctrl+v` to paste all the selected text.

**RegEx Explanation**

I'll break the expression into multiple parts.

`"` - This begins matching text starting with a double quote.
`[^"]` - This matches all text that does not include another double quote - important, because if we did match quotes we would start matching everything in the file after the first quote! Not what we want. The `^` symbol is the negation character in RegEx - it indicates to *not* match what comes next.
`+"` - Forces us to only match text that eventually ends in another double quote. This prevents us from matching, say, the final quote in the document to the end of the document, and ends all of the matches we started previously without overflowing into the stuff we don't want to match.

I imagine there are prettier ways to do this but I also expect that this covers what you need. If you have any problems with this, let me know!

Oh, and as a final note, part of the reason why I recommended Sublime is because it supports multiple cursors, which lets it select different parts of text simultaneously with ease. Try opening a document and `ctrl+middle click`ing in a few different spots, and then start typing.

*Edit*

Haha, I completely neglected to look in the most obvious spot in Notepad++ - the find tool - for built-in RegEx. You can do it pretty much the same way, but there wasn't a nice way to select all the text. The simplest thing was to click "Find all in Current Document", and then select all the text generated in the Find window at the bottom. But that is not as pretty as how Sublime manages it.

Comment: The question seems resolved, but what would you do if the quote is interrupted by a line break?

Comment: @KardNails I don't think a line break will affect this - I did some testing and it doesn't appear to. The newline character is `\n`, and that is matched during the negation of the quote.

Comment: Interesting. Can you explain why this `".*?"` only searches for matching characters on the same line unless I add `\s`?

Comment: @KardNails I am unsure about that. The `\s` delimiter matches all whitespace including spaces and tabs, so it would likely match most quotes in OP's question. That being said, it's still accounted for in RegEx I posted above. I was unable to recreate a quote with newlines in it that didn't match my RegEx. What is the exact expression you are using?

Comment: Nothing specific. I was just trying to understand why using `.*?` will only search on each separate line. Isn't `.` supposed to match any character? Wouldn't that include spaces, tabs and line breaks?

Comment: @KardNails Oh, I misunderstood what you were asking me before. Check http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html but basically a period `.` matches anything BUT a newline character

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Ctrl + H
2. Find what : ^(\l+)
3. Replace with :       (empty)
4. Replace all

[image]

Comment: What is that regex supposed to do?